# Caching WCF Proxy?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, proxy, channelfactory

I am trying to use Channel Factory and caching it in my asp.net mvc.
I am using PerSession Instance mode as I need to know the state.
Because of this I cannot close the proxy immediately. And I dont want
to reopen ,close proxy everytime.
If I leave the proxy open it is timing out at the 12th time. I can
increase the concurrent session timeout but I want to know if it is
the right approach to go.
I am new to WCF so pardon If my question is stupid.
-Thanks in advance
Pratt

Comment: Why do you wawnt to cache it?

Comment: Let me explain you the scenario. The user will login and all the data is coming from wcf service hosted on a different site. So for the same user the proxy should hold good for accessing all the different data part of the services. I dont want to create/open a proxy each and everytime to access the data service. I am caching it in Session Start event of the global.asax and resusing it for all my data retreival. Is there any other approach that is better in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer maybe activating the slidingExpiration property in the forms authentication element, although by default this is turned on. With this, after each call the timer is reset to the timeout value so the session stays active whilst it's in use.

See this [MSDN Link: Forms Authentication & slidingExpiration property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx)

EDIT - response to comment:

Yes, when the session timeout is reached you will need to reauthenticate before being able to accesss the services again. You should set the timeout value to the length of inactivity (in minutes) that you would consider the user is no longer active (default 30 mins), then the sliding expiration will reset this value if the user keeps calling. I'd try doing some simple tests with the timeout set to 1 minute with different scenarios to prove it to yourself.

Comment: This is well and good, but what happens to my proxy if I dont close and it time's out. Does the clr takes care of cleaning it up?